# Unable to Transfer spring-boot-starter-parent from maven repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, maven-2

Below is my pom.xml.
I am getting exceptions while fetching the spring-starter-parent from maven repo.
what is it that I should specify in my relative path :
What I tried: Relative path as ../pom.xml, .., ../ All pointing to wrong as I understand that this jar file should be served over https then why we should give a relative path? As in my understating relative path is given when project is in the local and we need to specify the location of parent pom.xml.
For spring-starter-parent it to be served from "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.1.RELEASE.pom" we shouldn't need a relative path..

But as I am getting errors I tried those things as well.

Please help in letting me know what is wrong with the pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/21346899/packages/maven</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>gitlab-maven</id>
            <url>https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/21346899/packages/maven</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <groupId>myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp.module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <spring-boot.repackage.skip>true</spring-boot.repackage.skip>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.4.10</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.leangen.graphql</groupId>
            <artifactId>spqr</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- GraphQL dependencies -->
        <dependency> <!-- generates GraphQL schema from data model classes -->
            <groupId>com.introproventures</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-jpa-query-schema</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.15</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring boot dependencies -->
        <dependency> <!-- provides the functionality to support our endpoints through web protocols -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- hosts our schema at the /graphql endpoint in our spring
                context -->
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- a web based UI for interacting with the /graphql endpoint, with knowledge
                of the schema at the endpoint -->
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.salomonbrys.kotson</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotson</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda date time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-extended-scalars</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CSV -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- misc. dependencies -->
        <dependency> <!-- unit testing -->
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.andrewoma.kwery</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>0.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Startinn Codebase -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>startinn</groupId>
            <artifactId>startinn.codebase</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                        <arg>-Xemit-jvm-type-annotations</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The exception I get is :
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.1.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for startinn:startinn.conso:0.0.1: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.1.RELEASE from/to jitpack.io (https://jitpack.io): transfer failed for https://jitpack.io/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.1.RELEASE.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 13
@
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project startinn:startinn.conso:0.0.1 (/Users/.../GitHub/myapp-service/backend/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for startinn:startinn.conso:0.0.1: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.1.RELEASE from/to jitpack.io (https://jitpack.io): transfer failed for https://jitpack.io/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.1.RELEASE.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 13: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

Comment: Also when I tried removing repos to jitpack etc I get this error: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for startinn:startinn.conso:0.0.1: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.3.1.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.1.RELEASE.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

Comment: I also saw most of the projects are showing : Cannot resolve unable to find valid certification path to requested target
I can't understand which certificate

Comment: The problem is: SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested targe` this means either old JDK ? Which version of JDK do you use? or via firewall/proxy?

Comment: We are using 17. version of JDK. The pom file has 1.8 version I tried changing from 1.8 to 17 but it doesn't work. I can't find 1.8 JDK download link in oracle.  The VPN I have is Zscaler. Firewall internally if company is using am not aware. Also I downloaded the file manually placed in my m2 folder still its not picking from there and still trying to download the starter-parent pom.